# How to get current days high in a minute timeframe? MQL4

Tags: mql4, metatrader4, mql

I'm new in MQL. I want to make a custom indicator that will return current day's highest price in a 1 minute timeframe. If I write:

```
current_day_high= iHigh(0,PERIOD_D1, 0);
```

Will it return current days high price?

In an 1M timeframe it should be changing during the day until reaches the highest price and become static.

How I can check if my custom indicator returns the values I want. Is there a way to store indicators values to check the calculations?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The correct usage of [iHigh](https://docs.mql4.com/series/ihigh) is as follows.

```
double  iHigh(
   string           symbol,          // symbol
   int              timeframe,       // timeframe
   int              shift            // shift
   );
```

Therefore you should be using

```
iHigh(NULL, PERIOD_D1, 0);
```

This will return the current days `High` price.

You can store any values as variables. If you feel the need to check the high (and I'm not sure why you would need to), you could use `iHigh()` with the current timeframe combined with [`iHighest()`](https://docs.mql4.com/series/ihighest).